# Convert 1 into any positive integer using only the operations *3 and /2

Tags: code-challenge, math

Any positive integer can be obtained by starting with **1** and applying a sequence of operations, each of which is either **"multiply by 3"** or **"divide by 2, discarding any remainder"**.

**Examples** (writing f for *3 and g for /2):

`4 = 1 *3 *3 /2 = 1 ffg`
`6 = 1 ffggf = 1 fffgg`
`21 = 1 fffgfgfgggf`

Write a program with the following behavior:

**Input**: any positive integer, via stdin or hard-coded. (If hard-coded, the input numeral will be excluded from the program length.) 
**Output**: a string of f's and g's such that `<input> = 1 <string>` (as in the examples). Such a string in reverse order is also acceptable. NB: The output contains only f's and g's, or is empty.

The winner is the entry with the fewest bytes of *program-plus-output* when 41 is the input.

Comment: How do you know this is true?

Comment: @marinus this is believed to be true ( but not proven yet). looking for some proof.

Comment: @marinus, you can prove that it's possible by descent (or equivalently by strong induction). Case-split on `x mod 3`: if `x=3y` construct y and then apply `f`; if `x=3y+1` construct `2y+1` and apply `f` then `g`; if `x=3y+2` then it gets complicated but essentially is recursive.

Comment: On a separate note, must the output be in application order or would composition order also be acceptable?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Either way is OK.

Comment: @marinus - See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521449/every-two-positive-integers-are-related-by-a-composition-of-these-two-functions). For the purpose of this challenge, assume it's true.

Comment: Hi! Please clarify if the code and output need to include (and count for score) any characters preceding the string of **f**'s and **g**'s.  I'm seeing some solutions include the `"1  "` in their code, output, and character count while others don't.

Comment: @DarrenStone "a string of f's and g's" is a clear definition, isn't it?

Comment: @Howard, I was thrown by the full `<input> = 1 <string>` being written in `"code font"` in both the examples and output spec but upon another reading, you're absolutely right. Thanks! Code fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### GolfScript, score 64 (43-2+23)

```
0{)1.$2base:s{{3*}{2/}if}/41=!}do;s{103^}%+
```

(41 is hardcoded, therefore -2 characters for the score). The output is

```
fffgffggffggffgggffgggg
```

which is 23 characters (without newline). By construction the code guarantees that it always returns (one of) the shortest representations.

Comment: Quoting user [Darren Stone](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9496/darren-stone) in [a suggested edit](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4581) on this post: "I am unable to leave a comment here so I will leave an edit. This output does not include the first two characters "1 " nor are those reflected in score. Should be an easy fix and still an incredibly short solution. Cheers!" (I rejected, but thought I should carry the message)

Comment: @Doorknob The challenge states that the `"1 "` should not be included in the output.

Answer (score 3):

We're getting dirty, friends!

**JAVA <del>210 207</del>  199 characters**

```
public class C{public static void main(String[] a){int i=41;String s="";while(i>1){if(i%3<1){s+="f";i/=3;}else if(i%3<2){s+="g";i+=i+1;}else{s+="g";i+=i+(Math.random()+0.5);}}System.out.println(s);}}
```

non-golfed:

```
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        int i = 41;
        String s = "";
        while (i > 1) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                s += "f";
                i /= 3;
            } else {
                if (i % 3 == 1) {
                    s += "g";
                    i += i + 1;
                } else {
                    s += "g";
                    i += i + (Math.random() + 0.5);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

output : depending on the faith of the old gods, the shortest i had was 30. Note that the output must be read from the right.

**234**

```
1 ggfgfgfgfggfggfgffgfggggfgffgfggfgfggggfgffgfggfgfggfgfggfgfgggggfffgfggfgfggfgfgggffgggggfffgfggggfgffgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggggfgffgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggfgfggggggggggggfgfgfggggfgfgfggfffgfgfggffgfgfggfgfggggffgfgfffff
```

**108**

```
1 gggffgfgfggggggfggggfgffggggfgfgfgfgfgffgggfgggggfggfffggfgfffffgggffggfgfgggffggfgfgggffggggggfgfgffgfgfff
```

*edit* **45**

```
1 ggfgfgfgfgggfggfffgfggfgfgggggggffgffgfgfff
```

**points : <del>318</del> 199+30 = 229**

**edit1** (2*i+1)%3==0 --> (2*i) % 3 ==1

Nota Bene if you use Java 6 and not Java 7 while golfing, you can use

```
public class NoMain {
    static {
        //some code
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

39 characters structure instead of a standard structure which is 53 characters long.

Comment: `(2*i+1)%3==0` is equivalent to `i%3==1`

Comment: `if(X){A}else{if(Y){B}else{C}}` is longer than `if(X){A}else if(Y){B}else{C}`. Also you can replace your `==` conditions with shorter `<` conditions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor true, my solution still is ugly. I don't know if the random part makes the code shorter, but it sures makes the output crappier.

Comment: Your f/g strings begin with 'g' (which is supposed to stand for '/2'), so they will convert 1 to 0 instead of to 41. Changing the f's to g's and vice versa, also doesn't seem to give 41.

Comment: @r.e.s. Nah, the problem is that I put my chars in the wrong order (as I start with 41 and ends at 1). try fffgfgffgffgggggggfgfggfgfffggfgggfgfgfgg

Comment: OK, when I run your program, I do get valid answers. E.g., ggfgfgfgfggggfgggffgffgfgfff, i.e. fffgfgffgffgggfggggfgfgfgfgg in reverse order. (But the string you just quoted seems to be wrong.)

Comment: The core seems to work properly, I just need to reverse the output, gonna edit this.

Comment: Also, maybe you're including some trailing newline characters in your score? I find your current program length to be 204, so the output string I just quoted (of length 28) would give a score of 204 + 28 = 232.

Comment: I changed my source code many times, and the output is never the same (lowest I had was 30 chars long), so it's pretty sure the points aren't good right now

Comment: OK, but note that I commented earlier that either order is acceptable -- I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: If I'm correct, it's 229 points.

Comment: You may reduce the size considerably by converting the inner if/else into a ternary `?:`. And you can use `print` instead of `println`.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, score 124 (90-2+36)

```
x=41;m=f=g=0
while(3**f!=x)*(m!=x):
 f+=1;m=3**f;g=0
 while m>x:m/=2;g+=1
print'f'*f+'g'*g
```

90 chars of code (newlines as 1 each) - 2 for hard-coded input numeral + 36 chars of output

Output:

```
ffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggg
```

Comment: If you do `m=f=0` you can make the outer loop `while(n!=x)*(m!=x)` and remove the breaks. Brings it to 95 chars of code.

Comment: @Daniel: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  Thanks!  Your submission is still safely 10 chars ahead of me.  :)

Comment: You can further save a bit if you replace all `n` by`3**f`.

Comment: @Howard: Thanks. Net 3 char savings. :)

Comment: For input = 1, your program generates an error ("name 'g' is not defined", due to not entering the outer while-loop).

Comment: Good catch, @r.e.s.  Thank you!  That case is fixed now and I've also dropped the leading `"1 "` from my output count. Dropped a few chars in the process.

Comment: You could cut out another character by writing `print'f'*f+'g'*g`, which would give a score of 90-2+36 = 124.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, score 121 (87 - 2 + 36)

```
t=bin(41)
l,n,f=len(t),1,0
while bin(n)[:l]!=t:f+=1;n*=3
print(len(bin(n))-l)*'g'+f*'f'
```

Comment: @Darren, I wasn't sure how to interpret the output description, but you're probably right. I added the '1'. Thanks!

Comment: You can drop the '1' (again!)  Your original interpretation of output description was correct. Enjoy the Python lead, again! :-)

Comment: If you combined your 2nd, 3rd, and 4th lines into `l,n,f=len(t),1,0`, and removed the `'1',` from the print statement, your score would be 87-2+36 = 121.

Comment: Thanks guys - I dropped the `1,`. `l,n,f=len(t),1,0` gives the same number of characters, right? (For each variable, an `=` and a newline is replaced with two `,`s.)

Comment: If each newline is one character (e.g. UNIX-style LF), then the one-line and three-line versions have the same length. If each newline is two characters (e.g. MS Windows-style CR+LF), then the one-line version is two characters shorter than the three-line version. The score of 121 assumes one-character newlines.

Comment: True. I think LF and CRLF are both permissible in a sense since the Python interpreter accepts either... so I chose to use the shorter line break sequence :)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, score 89 (63 - 2 + 28)

```
$_=41;$_=${$g=$_%3||$_==21?g:f}?$_*2+$_%3%2:$_/3while$_>print$g
```

***Conjecture:*** If the naive approach described in my original solution below ever reaches a cycle, that cycle will be *[21, 7, 15, 5, 10, 21, ...]*. As there are no counter-examples for *1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>*, this seems likely to be true. To prove this, it would suffice to show that this is the only cycle which *can* exist, which I may or may not do at a later point in time.

The above solution avoids the cycle immediately, instead of guessing (wrongly), and avoiding it the second time through.

Output (28 bytes):

```
ggfgfgfgfggfggfgfgfggfgfgfff
```

---

### Perl, score 100 (69 - 2 + 33)

```
$_=41;1while$_>print$s{$_=$$g?$_*2+$_%3%2:$_/3}=$g=$_%3||$s{$_/3}?g:f
```

Using a guess-and-check approach. The string is constructed using inverse operations (converting the value to *1*, instead of the other way around), and the string becomes mirrored accordingly, which is allowed by the problem specification.

Whenever a non-multiple of three is encountered, it will be multiplied by two, adding one if the result would then be a multiple of three. When a multiple of three is encountered, it will be divided by three... unless this value has previously been encountered, indicating a cycle, hence guess-and-check.

Output (33 bytes):

```
ggfgfgfgfggfggfgffgfgggfggfgfgfff
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, score 103 (82-2+23)

*Note: I named my verbs `f` and `g`, not to be confused with output strings `f` and `g`.

Hard-coded:

```
f=:3 :'s=.1 for_a.y do.s=.((<.&-:)`(*&3)@.a)s end.'
'gf'{~#:(>:^:(41&~:@f@#:)^:_)1
```

General functions:

```
f=:3 :'s=.1 for_a.y do.s=.((<.&-:)`(*&3)@.a)s end.'
g=:3 :'''gf''{~#:(>:^:(y&~:@f@#:)^:_)1'
```

Did away with operating on blocks of binary numbers, which was the most important change as far as compacting `g`. Renamed variables and removed some whitespace for the heck of it, but everything's still functionally the same. (Usage: `g 41`)

#### J, score 197 (174+23)

```
f =: 3 : 0
acc =. 1
for_a. y do. acc =. ((*&3)`(<.&-:)@.a) acc end.
)

g =: 3 : 0
f2 =: f"1 f.
l =. 0$0
i =. 1
while. 0=$(l=.(#~(y&=@:f2))#:i.2^i) do. i=.>:i end.
'fg'{~{.l
)
```

Output:
`ffffffffggggggggfgffggg`

`f` converts a list of booleans into number, using 0s as `*3` and 1s as `/2` (and `floor`). `#:i.2^i` creates a rank 2 array containing all the rank 1 boolean arrays of length `i`.